# Laravel 9 - Not able to generate token with passport

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-passport, laravel-9

The below is my login function in laravel 9 project. I am trying to create an authentication token through `laravel-passport`.

```
public function login(Request $request) {
    $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();
    if ($user) {
        if (Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
            $token = $user->createToken('Laravel Password Grant Client')->accessToken;
            $response['token'] = $token;
            return response($response, 200);
        } else {
            $response = ["message" => "Password mismatch"];
      

      return response($response, 422);
            }
        }
}
```

The response I am getting is,

```
{
    "token": {
        "name": "Laravel Password Grant Client",
        "abilities": [
            "*"
        ],
        "tokenable_id": 1,
        "tokenable_type": "App\\Models\\User",
        "updated_at": "2022-07-04T05:58:36.000000Z",
        "created_at": "2022-07-04T05:58:36.000000Z",
        "id": 62
    }
}
```

I am not getting any token here.
Please help me out to fix this.

Comment: Instead of `->accessToken` at the end, try `->plainTextToken` to get it's plain text value.

Comment: I am getting `->plainTextToken`. But are we supposed to use it as the api token.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

accessToken is correct just don't forget use:

```
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
```

instead of:

```
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
```

This is correct:  `$token = $user->createToken('Laravel Password Grant Client')->accessToken;`

Answer (score 1):

you are generate token using where condition use attempt function like this -

```
        if(Auth::attempt($request->only('email','password'))){
         /** @var \App\Models\User $user **/
        $user=Auth::user();
        $success['token']=$user->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken;
        return response()->json(['success'=>'login successfully',$success]);
        }
```

its working properly

Answer (score 0):

you have to log in user first after the login token is created.

$data['email'] = request email

$data['password'] = request password

```
Auth::attempt($data);    
$loginUser = Auth::user();
$token = $loginUser->createToken('Laravel Password Grant Client')->accessToken;
$loginUser->accessToken = $token;
```

Comment: Din't work. I am getting `BadMethodCallException: Method Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::attempt does not exist.` error.

Comment: try one more time with guard name 'web'
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

**Auth::guard('web')->attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password]);**

Comment: Tried.. Still not working.. The problem is with `attempt`. So we cannot use that.

Comment: show me your route

Comment: the problem is not with attempt, problem is guard either you have to by pass that specific route 
is this route for API?

Comment: `Route::post('register', [UserController::class, 'store']);
Route::resource('products', ProductsController::class);
Route::post('login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);` are my routes

Comment: Is there anything I should  do with routes ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `plainTextToken` instead of `accessToken`.

```php
$token = $user->createToken('Laravel Password Grant Client')->plainTextToken;
```

It will give you a string, that you can use as API token.

Comment: Yeah. I tried this. But can we use this as a bearer token ?